# how to instantiate an object from a class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am learning Kotlin, and I googled how to create a class in kotlin. So, I created the below class as a test.
In the main activity, I am trying to instantiate an object from the class Board, but i get the following error:

```
classifier Board does not have a companion object
```

please let me know how to intantiate an object of an the class Board?

**MainActivity**:

```
class ActMain : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_act_main)

    Board board = new Board(name = "ABC");
}
}
```

**Board.kt**:

```
data class Board(val name: String) {
    var age: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: That's not valid Kotlin

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Kotlin does not use `new`.

```
Board board = new Board(name = "ABC");
```

is incorrect. Use

```
val board = Board("ABC")
```

Your code reflects the Java syntax... sort of. Kotlin has type inference, so you don't need to specify the class type. However, if you do specify it, it's different from Java:

```
val board: Board = Board("ABC")
```

Semi-colons are also not generally used in Kotlin, although they won't break the compilation if you use them.

<s>`name = "ABC"` just isn't valid syntax no matter if it's Java or Kotlin.</s> Actually it is (from @hotkey): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments

Comment: `name = "ABC"` is actually a correct way to pass the argument in Kotlin, see [Functions / Named Arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments) in the language reference.

Comment: Semicolons are required in Kotlin when you place multiple statements or expressions in a single line of code.

Answer (score 4):

**Unlike Java, in Kotlin this is the correct way**

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class ActMain : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_act_main)

        val board = Board("ABC")
        board.age = 12
    }
}
```

**Board.kt**

```kotlin
class Board(val name: String) {
    var age: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to forget java

```
val board = Board("name")
```

Answer (score 1):

> in kotlin

when you want to declare new object yon can do like this.

```
val board = Board("ABC")
```

if you declare object by using **val** keyword. it look as you use **final** in java. the variable which you declared can not recreate again.

```
var board = Board("ABC")
```

if you use var to declare it look as normal variable in java

Anyway in kotlin you will see something that It doesn't contain in java such as 
scoping function as link below. it will help you write your code is more easily.

https://kotlin.guide/scoping-functions

I hope this help :)